# parallel arrays read from textfile

Tags: java, arrays

So i have this code so far and i want the scanner to read from a file and i want the second array to increment every time a word is repeated from the first array...but it messes up for the first category....any ideas?

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(new File("Categories.txt"));
    String category=sc.nextLine();
    int catnum=sc.nextInt();
    int count[]=new int[catnum];
    ArrayList<String>anim=new ArrayList<String>();
    while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {
        String temp=sc.nextLine();
        anim.add(temp);
    }

    Collections.sort(anim);
    System.out.println(anim);

    for(int i=0;i<count.length;i++)
    {
        String x=anim.get(0);
        for(int j=0;j<anim.size();j++)
        {
            if(anim.get(j).equals(x))
            {
                count[i]++;
                anim.remove(j--);
            }

        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<count.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(count[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`count.size()` returns 0 the first time since you never added anything to it, so you never enter in the loop. Use `scategories.size()` instead.

Comment: I actually changed it...can you take a look at it now please?

Comment: You completely changed the code... It is unclear what you are trying to achieve.